# Android flavor+build type specific dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I have flavours in my `build.gradle` file, `staging`, `stable` and `production`, as well as the default build types `debug` and `release`. I have different AAR files for each and every one of these, for example I have an AAR that I want to use for `stagingDebug`, a different one for `stagingRelease`, as well as `stableDebug` and all other variants.

I am able to use `releaseImplementation ('xxxx@aar')` and `stagingImplementation ('yyyy@aar')`, but I'm not able to use `stagingReleaseImplementation ('zzzzz@aar')`

Is there any way I can use flavor+build type specific dependencies?

Comment: were u able to find solution?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to define a variable in your top level `build.gradle` file:

```
project.ext.BuildCmdLine = "Release"

android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        project.ext.BuildCmdLine= variant.buildType.name // Sets the current build type
    }
}
```

Then in your module's `build.gradle` files, you can set the dependencies you want to use based on `project.ext.BuildCmdLine`:

```
dependencies {

    if (project.BuildCmdLine == "Release") {
        api(name: 'yourlib-release', ext: 'aar')
    } else {
        api(name: 'yourlib-debug', ext: 'aar')
    }
}
```